# Save model error with AUTO_INCREMENT trigger in django

Tags: mysql, django, triggers

Here is my Django source to save model.

```
e = Element(title = title, description = des, location = city, date = timezone.now())
e.save()
```

and Here is my mysql trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `ins_blog` AFTER INSERT ON `blog`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO snippet
    SET 
        id = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`),
        title = NEW.title,
        snippet = NEW.description,
        source_site = 'KJOBUS',
        location = NEW.location,
        date = NEW.date;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

without trigger, it works fine. I can save.
in mysql, trigger works fine without any error or warning.

However, when I try saving data trough Django, warning is came out.

```
Exception Type: Warning
Exception Value:    
Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statement is unsafe because it invokes a trigger or a stored function that inserts into an AUTO_INCREMENT column. Inserted values cannot be logged correctly.
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in _warning_check, line 92
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
```

Where is no way to insert data with trigger in django?

Comment: It looks like a case of Django trying to protect you against unsafe behavior in your database. To learn why django is trying to do this, please read http://grimoire.ca/mysql/choose-something-else

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, That means I have to insert myself without trigger?

Comment: Yes, you will have to insert yourself without a trigger, but you can use django's post_save signal to essentially write a trigger in the application layer. See the example below.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, I made trigger in the application layer myself. but, I  had no idea how to lock the row!. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Replacing Mysql Triggers with Django Signals

You can use Django's post_save signal to replace your mysql trigger. The following is exactly equivalent.

```
from django.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@reciever(post_save, sender=Element) # or sender=Blog, your example is unclear
def create_snippet(sender, instance, created, raw, **kwargs):
    if created and not raw: # raw=True when loading from fixtures
        Snippet.objects.create(
            title=instance.title,
            description=instance.description,
            source_site='KJOBUS',
            location=instance.description,
            date=instance.date,
        )
```

REF: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save